# Formula for a square of any number ending with $5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In an exercise I'm asked the following:

> Note that: $\underline {1}5^2= \underline{2}25,\ \underline {3}5^2= \underline{12}25,\ \underline {8}5^2= \underline{72}25,\ \underline {10}5^2= \underline{110}25$. Find a rule to evaluate the square of any natural number that ends with $5$ and prove it.

So, looking at the parted I noticed the following: We take the number before the final $5$ (let's call it $n$), and then the square will be $n^2 + n$ followed by $25$. For example: $\underline{65}5^2 \to 65^2 + 65 = 4290$ so $655^2 = \underline{4290}25$. Although I found a general formula I'm not being able to prove this. I thought of the following:

Let $n = 5 + \sum_{k=1}^n a_k10^k$. Let's define $\alpha:= \sum_{k=1}^n a_k10^{k-1}$. Then: $n^2 = 100({\alpha}^2+ \alpha) + 25$. I'm not sure if this is the right way to put this pattern, but how can I prove this?

Comment: There is no need for the $\sum$ stuff. Just saying $n=5+10\alpha$ (where $\alpha$ is an integer) from the start is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Arthur pointed out in the comments, all you need is to write $n = 10 \alpha + 5$. Then,

$n^2=(10 \alpha + 5)^2 = 100 \alpha^2 + 100 \alpha + 25 = 100( \alpha^2 + \alpha) + 25.$

Answer (score 1):

The rule for the square of any number ending in $5$ is to take all the digits preceding the $5$, multiply it by itself incremented by $1$, and append to the result the digits $25$.  For example, $$65^2=\underline{6}5^2=\underline{42}25\qquad(6\times7=42).$$

*Proof.*  A number $n$ ending in $5$ satisfies $$n=5+10k,\quad k\in\Bbb Z.$$
As such, we have
\begin{align}
n&=5+10k\\
n^2&=(5+10k)^2\\
&=25+100k+100k^2\\
&=25+100k(1+k)
\end{align}
as desired.